# Socket.io connection between Frappe and Flutter

Tags: flutter, socket.io, frappe

I try to Socket API connection between Frappe and Flutter but no ,But i can't get any response or any errors also there is no request log in the bench log.

flutter Code

```
IO.Socket socket = IO.io("http://myUrl:8000", IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).enableForceNew().build());
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
  socket.onConnect((data) => print("connected"));
socket.on("connected", (data) {
print (data);
  
});
 socket.connect();
super.initState();
  }
```

Frappe code

```
import frappe
def test1():
    frappe.publish_realtime('a',{'name':'b'})
```